# Private .ctor абстрактного класса

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день!

Тут на днях поймал интересный кейс:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
     private BaseClass(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor of BaseClass, accept i:" + i);
    }
}

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
// В этом месте, естественно, возникает ошибка компиляции, т.к. нет доступа к private конструктору базового класса и компилятор не пропускает код в компиляцию
    public DerivedClass(int i, int z) : base(2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor of DerivedClass, accept i:{0}, z:{1}", i, z);
    }
}
```

Скомпилировано в VS2017, .Net 4.6.1

Собственно вот в чём вопрос:
Почему компилятор C# позволяет объявить единственный private конструктор базового класса, если это приведёт к невозможности его наследования?

Если убрать DerivedClass и оставить только базовый, то компилятор не видит проблем и свободно компилирует код, с полностью непригодным классом.
Подобный код запросто компилируется:

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private BaseClass(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor of BaseClass, accept i:" + i);
    }
}
```

Или же это можно как то использовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приватный конструктор у абстрактного класса может использоваться:

1. чтобы ограничить множество наследников класса вложенными классами (например, для создания закрытой иерархии классов):

   ```
   public abstract class BaseClass
   {
       private BaseClass(int i)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Constructor of BaseClass, accept i:" + i);
       }

       public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
       {
           public DerivedClass() : base(2) { } // разрешено
       }
   }


   public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
   {
       public DerivedClass() : base(2) { } // ошибка
   }
   ```
2. вместо модификатора static при объявлении классов являющихся наборами статических методов (актуально для старых версий языка, где не было статических классов):

   ```
   public abstract class Utils
   {
       private Utils() {}

       public static void Foo()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
       }
   }
   ```
3. для объявления невозможного типа, переменные которого могут иметь только значение null, а в not nullable варианте не могут существовать:

   ```
   public abstract class Void 
   {
       private Void() { }
   }
   ```

Впрочем, в двух последних случаях модификатор abstract - вкусовщина и может не использоваться.

*Ну и последнее. У компилятора нет задачи проверки осмысленности вашей программы - а значит не у всех комбинаций языковых конструкций есть хоть какой-то смысл. Особенно богата на потенциально бессмысленные конструкции последняя версия языка, где по-убирали многие старые ограничения с мотивацией "а почему бы и нет?" :-)*